# Get Class from Field

Tags: java

I'm looping over the fields of ClassA. If one of the fields is from type ClassB, I want to loop over its fields too, and so on.

However, I'm not sure how to get the Class from ClassB properly.

I tried field.getType(), field.getClass() and field.get(). None of them worked properly.

When I loop over the fields of ClassB using the above mentioned functions, I get generic fields but not the ones from ClassB.

I suspect that the issue is that the first two functions don't give me a reference, while the last function fails with "Can not set DataClass field ParentClass.testClass to java.lang.Class."

I'm a bit stuck. How can I get the Class from a Field?

(Example repo to reproduce: [GitHub R](https://github.com/SvenWollinger/FieldIssue/tree/main/src)

This is the code I use to test this:

```
public static void load(Object obj) throws IllegalAccessException {
    for(Field f : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        System.out.println("Found: " + f);
        if(f.getType() == DataClass.class)
            load(f.get(f.getType()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code into your question, instead of linking to an external location.

Comment: The first parameter of `Field.get` is the object to get the value from. So `f.get(obj)` should work.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I did try that, but i always get ```Can not set DataClass field ParentClass.testClass to java.lang.Class```, no matter how i tell it what class to load. Do you know how id have to enter it from the code sample i edited into my post?

Comment: @SvenWollinger: please [edit] your question to provide complete [mre] in the question (don't depend on external links for that!) and also include the *full* stack trace that you get and not just the exception message.

Comment: And for the given context, maybe create two minimal example classes: so that you can really show us all things we would need to run this on our end.

Comment: It's pretty obious that the issue is `f.get(f.getType())` so I don't see what the close vote was for. It should be `f.get(obj)` or alternatively the function should only care about the classes and not object instances at all.

Comment: @kutschkem: the inital question contained no code at all, just a link to github. Even the current state is suboptimal, but not quite as bad.